# Checking if database contains table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I created the coding for a program to check if table exists in database. But it keeps underlining restrictions in the coding. 
Error   23  Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'
Can you please tell me what i did wrong and check if the rest of my coding correct.

Here is the coding:

```
    Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(SQL_Loader("", My.Settings.SQL_Win_Auth, _
         My.Settings.SQL_Username, My.Settings.SQL_Password, My.Settings.SQL_Server_Name, _
         My.Settings.SQL_DB_Name))
    Dim Cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim Reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader

    Cmd.Connection = cn

    cn.Open()

    Dim restrictions As String
    restrictions = "Pastel_Companies"
    Dim dbTbl As DataTable = cn.GetSchema("Pastel_Companies", restrictions)

    If dbTbl.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Table Does Not Exist")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Table exists")
    End If
```

Thank you for any help given

Comment: Pastel_Companies is the name of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to call [GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136367.aspx) is the following

```
Dim restrictions As String() = new String() {Nothing, Nothing, "Pastel_Companies"}
Dim dbTbl As DataTable = cn.GetSchema("TABLES", restrictions)
```

The first parameter is the collection that you want to check for the existence of the object (in your case you want to check the `TABLES` collection)
The second parameter contains an array of restrictions. This array changes following the collection that you want to search.  For the `TABLES` collection you should apply three restrictions `database`, `owner` and `tablename`.
The restrictions should appear in the exact order expected, and if you haven't a value to specify you pass a null value (Nothing in VB)

Comment: Thank you that really helped and it works:)! I f i could vote yor answer i would:)

Answer (score 0):

The offers a pretty good clue; you're passing a string as the second argument to [GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema.aspx) instead of a one-dimensional array of strings.

Try this:

```
Dim restrictions() as string = { Nothing, Nothing, "Pastel_Companies" }
Dim dbTbl As DataTable = cn.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions)
```